# Сеть для graylog в docker-compose

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, docker, proxy, elasticsearch

Проблема заключаеться в том, что после того как я поместил graylog, elastic и mongo в одну внутренюю сеть докера рядом с nginx для накрутки днс, graylog перестает отображать фронтенд по доменному адресу. Ошибок вроде нет, но мне кажеться что какие-то компонеты не подтягиваються от elastic. Все остальные сервисы в контейнерах на которые нартучен dns по аналогии работают нормально. Прокси везде отрабатывает. Ошибок в логе nginx не обнаружено.

````
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.8.10
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11

  graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:3.3.5
    volumes:
      - graylog_data:/usr/share/graylog/data
    environment:
     
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=2FLGyoUpYDhkVMSo89EsSxqF84DMxSnuZgpHFTqepBti671f2H4l8RQzNRWB51HGYVeLASVDlo3jYLkDxjLvoQPjE7uWnHKh
      
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=564a5fcf9ceb22a225acd62ddf728fd92f666a02348fbabb2607454659c89965
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://88.198.189.243:9000/
    links:
      - mongodb:mongo
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      # Graylog web interface and REST API
      - 9000:9000
      # Syslog TCP
      - 1514:1514
      # Syslog UDP
      - 1514:1514/udp
      # GELF TCP
      - 12201:12201
      # GELF UDP
      - 12201:12201/udp
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.12
    ```

Логи graylog контейнера:

    2020-09-22 09:15:09,337 INFO : org.graylog2.shared.initializers.PeriodicalsService - Not starting [org.graylog2.periodical.ContentPackLoaderPeriodical] periodical. Not configured to run on this node.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,337 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.GarbageCollectionWarningThread] periodical, running forever.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,345 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexerClusterCheckerThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [30s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,348 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRetentionThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [300s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,348 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRotationThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [10s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,349 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.NodePingThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [1s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,349 INFO : org.graylog.plugins.pipelineprocessor.periodical.LegacyDefaultStreamMigration - Legacy default stream has no connections, no migration needed.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,354 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.VersionCheckThread] periodical in [300s], polling every [1800s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,354 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.ThrottleStateUpdaterThread] periodical in [1s], polling every [1s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,356 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:65}] to mongo:27017
2020-09-22 09:15:09,362 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.events.ClusterEventPeriodical] periodical in [0s], polling every [1s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,364 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.events.ClusterEventCleanupPeriodical] periodical in [0s], polling every [86400s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,366 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.ClusterIdGeneratorPeriodical] periodical, running forever.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,367 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:66}] to mongo:27017
2020-09-22 09:15:09,368 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRangesMigrationPeriodical] periodical, running forever.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,374 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRangesCleanupPeriodical] periodical in [15s], polling every [3600s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,379 INFO : org.graylog2.shared.initializers.PeriodicalsService - Not starting [org.graylog2.periodical.UserPermissionMigrationPeriodical] periodical. Not configured to run on this node.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,379 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.ConfigurationManagementPeriodical] periodical, running forever.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,384 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:67}] to mongo:27017
2020-09-22 09:15:09,385 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.LdapGroupMappingMigration] periodical, running forever.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,386 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexFailuresPeriodical] periodical, running forever.
2020-09-22 09:15:09,402 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.TrafficCounterCalculator] periodical in [0s], polling every [1s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,404 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.indexer.fieldtypes.IndexFieldTypePollerPeriodical] periodical in [0s], polling every [3600s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,406 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog.scheduler.periodicals.ScheduleTriggerCleanUp] periodical in [120s], polling every [86400s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,412 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog.plugins.sidecar.periodical.PurgeExpiredSidecarsThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [600s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,425 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog.plugins.sidecar.periodical.PurgeExpiredConfigurationUploads] periodical in [0s], polling every [600s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,438 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog.plugins.views.search.db.SearchesCleanUpJob] periodical in [3600s], polling every [28800s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,439 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog.events.periodicals.EventNotificationStatusCleanUp] periodical in [120s], polling every [86400s].
2020-09-22 09:15:09,444 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog.plugins.collector.periodical.PurgeExpiredCollectorsThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [3600s].
2020-09-22 09:15:10,037 INFO : org.graylog2.shared.initializers.JerseyService - Enabling CORS for HTTP endpoint

Логи elastic контейнера:

    [2020-09-22T09:19:03,734][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,735][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,735][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,735][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,735][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,735][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,735][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,735][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [parent-join]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [percolator]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [reindex]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [repository-url]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,736][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] loaded module [tribe]
[2020-09-22T09:19:03,737][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IydRrw7] no plugins loaded
[2020-09-22T09:19:07,264][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [IydRrw7] using discovery type [zen] and host providers [settings]
[2020-09-22T09:19:07,738][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [IydRrw7] initialized
[2020-09-22T09:19:07,739][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [IydRrw7] starting ...
[2020-09-22T09:19:07,872][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [IydRrw7] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2020-09-22T09:19:07,893][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [IydRrw7] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2020-09-22T09:19:10,970][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [IydRrw7] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined), reason: new_master {IydRrw7}{IydRrw7lSBCRibR_7MIV_w}{RNANG_WEQ5CViJwdMfW7Aw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}
[2020-09-22T09:19:10,991][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [IydRrw7] new_master {IydRrw7}{IydRrw7lSBCRibR_7MIV_w}{RNANG_WEQ5CViJwdMfW7Aw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {IydRrw7}{IydRrw7lSBCRibR_7MIV_w}{RNANG_WEQ5CViJwdMfW7Aw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)]])
[2020-09-22T09:19:11,027][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [IydRrw7] publish_address {172.20.0.11:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
[2020-09-22T09:19:11,028][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [IydRrw7] started
[2020-09-22T09:19:11,189][WARN ][o.e.d.c.j.Joda           ] [IydRrw7] 'y' year should be replaced with 'u'. Use 'y' for year-of-era. Prefix your date format with '8' to use the new specifier.
[2020-09-22T09:19:11,476][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [IydRrw7] recovered [3] indices into cluster_state
[2020-09-22T09:19:12,164][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [IydRrw7] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[graylog_0][0]] ...]).
[2020-09-22T09:19:14,891][WARN ][o.e.d.r.a.a.i.RestGetMappingAction] [IydRrw7] [types removal] The parameter include_type_name should be explicitly specified in get mapping requests to prepare for 7.0. In 7.0 include_type_name will default to 'false', which means responses will omit the type name in mapping definitions.

Лог mongo

    2020-09-22T09:20:45.878+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2020-09-22T09:20:45.878+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7513M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2020-09-22T09:20:47.775+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1600766447:775861][1:0x7f414cb47a40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 3/3119872
2020-09-22T09:20:47.988+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1600766447:988130][1:0x7f414cb47a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 4
2020-09-22T09:20:48.106+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1600766448:106856][1:0x7f414cb47a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 4
2020-09-22T09:20:48.197+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1600766448:197045][1:0x7f414cb47a40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2020-09-22T09:20:48.246+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-09-22T09:20:48.246+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-09-22T09:20:48.246+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-09-22T09:20:48.246+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-09-22T09:20:48.258+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2020-09-22T09:20:48.259+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] listening via socket bound to 0.0.0.0
2020-09-22T09:20:48.260+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] listening via socket bound to /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2020-09-22T09:20:48.260+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2020-09-22T09:20:48.341+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42338 #1 (1 connection now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.341+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42338 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }
2020-09-22T09:20:48.347+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42340 #2 (2 connections now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42342 #3 (3 connections now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42340 conn2: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42344 #4 (4 connections now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42342 conn3: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42346 #5 (5 connections now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42344 conn4: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42348 #6 (6 connections now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.348+0000 I NETWORK  [conn5] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42346 conn5: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }
2020-09-22T09:20:48.349+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42350 #7 (7 connections now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.349+0000 I NETWORK  [conn6] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42348 conn6: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }
2020-09-22T09:20:48.349+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.12:42352 #8 (8 connections now open)
2020-09-22T09:20:48.349+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42350 conn7: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }
2020-09-22T09:20:48.349+0000 I NETWORK  [conn8] received client metadata from 172.20.0.12:42352 conn8: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.12.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.9.0-12-amd64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_265-b01" }

Graylog proxy conf:

    server {
  listen 80;
  server_name graylog.com;
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    alias /var/lib/dehydrated/acme-challenges;
   # allow all;
   # default_type "text/plain";
  }
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/graylog.whaleapp.team/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/graylog.whaleapp.team/privkey.pem;

  server_name graylog.com;

  location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Graylog-Server-URL http://$server_name/api;
    proxy_pass          http://172.20.0.12:9000;
    #proxy_read_timeout  90;
    #proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_redirect      http://172.20.0.12:9000 https://graylog.com;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
  }
}
````

Comment: А для чего вы указываете статические адреса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена с изменением строки proxy_set_header X-Graylog-Server-URL https://$server_name;